# Finding $x^2 - y^2 = ? $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$$-3\lt x\leq 4 $$
$$-4 \lt y \lt -1$$

$$x^2 - y^2 = ? $$

At first, I've squared the both inequality.

$$9\lt x^2 \leq 16 $$
$$16 \gt y^2 \gt 1$$

And multiplied the second inequality by $-1$

$$-16 \lt -y^2 \lt -1$$

However, I don't know how to combine these two inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that in fact

$$-3<x\leq4\Longrightarrow 0\leq x^{2}\leq 16$$

and

$$-16<-y^{2}<-1$$ as you wrote. If you add those two you get

$$-16<x^{2}-y^{2}<15$$

Comment: Why is it $-3<x\leq4\Longrightarrow 0\leq x^{2}\leq 16$?

Comment: @Busi You can't just square both sides if one side is positive and the other is negative, as you did. A simple example why it fails is to see that $x=0$ indeed satisfies $-3<x\leq 4$, but $x^{2}=0$ is not included in your range. A way to solve this is to divide the region into positive and negative parts: $-3<x\leq 4$ means that $-3<x<0$ **or** $0\leq x\leq 4$. Now you can square to get $0<x^{2}<9$ **or** $0\leq x^{2}\leq 16$. Finally combine this back into $0\leq x^{2}\leq 16$.

Comment: @Busi because $\inf|x|=0$ hence $\inf(x^2)=0$

Comment: so it it $(-7,15)$?